# how to get php array value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I was confused how  to get php made Array() value in Jquery.
Please Help some one.

My Array Structure is:

```
Var data = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 [date] => 2016-04-26 13:37:16 [member_id] => 46 [quantity] => 1 [costper_litre] => 40 [total_amount] => 40 [paid_amount] => 30 [balance_amount] => 10 [entry_date] => 26-04-2016 ) );
```

I was using to get value in jquery like this:

```
<script>
    var account_id = data['entry_date'];
    alert(account_id);
</script>
```

Error Giveing Undefined.

Comment: I don't quite see what is your real code. What code comes from PHP and what code comes from JQuery.

Comment: You appear unsure of the split between client- and server-side code. The code you have posted is pseudo code, not actual code. Ordinarily, JavaScript would have access to server-side content either via AJAX or by the server echo'ing out that data in the source code so that JavaScript can have access to it.

Comment: public function editoutput_entries($mid){
   $conn = $this->conn;
   $jsonData = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".CASH_BOOK." where id=$mid";
   
   $result=$conn->query($sql);
   $array = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $jsonData[] = $array;
   
   return $jsonData;
  }

Comment: this is real code and This array come from here

Comment: so the array is a php array? where are you converting it to a javascript array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
<?php
 $var = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 11 [date] => 2016-04-26 13:37:16 [member_id] => 46 [quantity] => 1 [costper_litre] => 40 [total_amount] => 40 [paid_amount] => 30 [balance_amount] => 10 [entry_date] => 26-04-2016 );
?>



 <script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
    Var data = <?php echo $var[]; ?>
     });
    </script>
```

or

```
<script>
    Var data = <?php print_r($var); ?>
 </script>
```

Comment: no i want  only  in jquery to show value from array

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode:

```
var data = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

Comment: i dont want in php

Comment: @WebsnapDesigns this is javascript code... you want to convert your php variable to javascript, which is what this does..

Comment: You need to post jquery array using ajax and save that array to php variable in php file..I think this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

try the following asuming you are using ajax;

```
   public function editoutput_entries($mid){ $conn = $this->conn; $jsonData = array(); $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".CASH_BOOK." where id=$mid"; $result=$conn->query($sql); $array = $result->fetch_assoc(); $jsonData['result'] = $array; return json_encode($jsonData); }
```

in ajax success function:

```
   success:function(data){
    var account_id = data.result.entry_date;
    alert(account_id);
}
```

Comment: how are you passing the values from php to the js?

Comment: ya from php to jquery

Comment: not working.....  and why u used     results   here ->   var account_id = data.result.entry_date;

Comment: i change your function that return the data

Comment: here is structure:   [{"id":"11","date":"2016-04-26 13:37:16","member_id":"46","quantity":"1","costper_litre":"40","total_amount":"40","paid_amount":"30","balance_amount":"10","entry_date":"26-04-2016"}]

Comment: `var data= [{"id":"11","date":"2016-04-26 13:37:16","member_id":"46","quantity":"1","costper_litre":"40","total_amount":"4‌​0","paid_amount":"30","balance_amount":"10","entry_date":"26-04-2016"}]; alert(data[0].date)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because `entry_date` `key` is not in `data` array, it's in zeroth index of `data`

Hence try :

```
  $account_id = data[0]['entry_date'];
  alert($account_id);`
```

Comment: also not coming saying undefined

Comment: is that array or an object ?

Comment: please write console.log(data); in script tag, and check what you are getting in browser console

Comment: whats the result of console.log(data); ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on JSON or just google "how to pass variables from PHP to JavaScript" there is a lot of information about the multiple ways this can be done. [Other StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

```
<script>
    data = JSON.parse(<?PHP echo json_encode($array); ?>);
</script>

<script>
    alert(data); //for testing purposes
    var account_id = data['entry_date'];
    alert(account_id);
</script>
```

Comment: $array should be replaced by the variable you have the array saved in.
You should update you question to contain a lot more information, you've given us a print_r of the php array, we need to know where you're setting it and where the jquery code is compared to the php code. it could be in 2 totally different files!

Better just read up on the other question i send you.